# How to render the value of variable from a HTML page?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, jinja2

suppose, If I have dictionary

```
game = [{'points': '534', 'Team': 'Ireland', 'Rating': '36', 'Matches': '15'}, {'points': '5146', 'Team': 'England Women', 'Rating': '129', 'Matches': '40'}, {'points': '5898', 'Team': 'Australia Women', 'Rating': '128', 'Matches': '46'},{'date-updated': '05 February 2018', 'match-type': "ICC Women's Championship"}]
```

If I wan't to use key's `'points'`,`'Team'`,`'Rating'`,`'Matches'`, I can use for loop like

```
{% for team in game %}
    <tr class="table table-bordered">
        <td>{{ team["Team"]}}</td>    
        <td>{{ team['Matches'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ team['points'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ team['Rating'] }}</td>
{% endif%}
```

and I can print these key's value.

How can  I  render the key value of `date-updated` and `match-type` without using for loop since there is only one set of dictionary present.

I tried to call it as bellow but it didn't print anything

```
<tr>
    <th class="bg-danger text-lg-left">{{game['date-updated']}} </th>
    <th class="bg-danger text-lg-right">{{game['match-type']}}</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without for loop you need to know the index of the array,

Following your example

```
<tr>
    <th class="bg-danger text-lg-left">{{game[3]['date-updated']}} </th>
    <th class="bg-danger text-lg-right">{{game[3]['match-type']}}</th>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative indexing if the position of the dictionary is always in the last.

**EX:**

```
game = [{'points': '534', 'Team': 'Ireland', 'Rating': '36', 'Matches': '15'}, {'points': '5146', 'Team': 'England Women', 'Rating': '129', 'Matches': '40'}, {'points': '5898', 'Team': 'Australia Women', 'Rating': '128', 'Matches': '46'},{'date-updated': '05 February 2018', 'match-type': "ICC Women's Championship"}]

print game[-1]['date-updated']
print game[-1]['match-type']
```

**Output:**

```
05 February 2018
ICC Women's Championship
```